# Create a layout with button only and transparent background in Android

Tags: android, layout, transparent

I want to create a layout containing only a button, i want the layout to be transparent more even more, i want it 'not to be there', in other words, i want my layout to be only a not full size 'window' but only the button size, so i will be able to continue using any app open behind my app.

i tried :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:windowBackground="@android:color/transparent" 
android:windowIsTranslucent="true" >

<ToggleButton android:id="@+id/lockButton"
    style="@style/lockToggle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">
</ToggleButton>
```

The background is really transparent but still a layer and the app in the back is not usable.

Comment: Your app in the background is not usable because as soon as you open this app you are trying to create, any other foreground app will go into its `onPause` state (and I believe it will even go to `onStop`) in which case you will no longer be able to interact with it. Check [here](http://www.herongyang.com/Android/Activity-onCreate-and-Callback-Methods.html) for more on the lifecycle on an app. AFAIK this isn't possible...

Comment: Do you need this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android ?

Comment: Or this: https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As u need to operate other apps , surely u need a service

Try to check about

[Creating a system overlay window (always on top)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-always-on-top-button-in-android)